# SSIS - Update error in For each loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis

[image]I have some .txt files which I am trying to import to my oledb destination.
I want to apply some updates to the data before extracting them in the .csv format. And am trying to achieve this through SSIS.

I have the below flow:

> 1>Execute sql task to truncate my existing table
>   2>Data flow task to import my flat file to the oledb dest
>   3>Execute sql task to update my data as per my needs.
>   4>Data flow task to export the data in csv file.

**Concerns here is:**
I have many such text files and I want to use **for each loop Container** in my package, 
My text file has vendor wise data say eg: tibco.txt, I want to import this file from a location and extract it to destination folder with the same name but with **.csv** extension.
I have used a variable that stores the name of the file each time the for loop runs and have set it in expressions : Connection String for the input flat file used in step 2 above.

My package runs fine until the 2nd step but fails to update the data at step 3.

**Error**: 
    [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "update tablename set          vendor_inventory = r..." failed with the following error: "Invalid column name     'HOSTNAME'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Does the `tablename` table have a `HOSTNAME` field in it? I think more details might help, like: are the text files all being imported into the same table or different tables?

Comment: @mendosi  yes, it has this field in it.the text files are imported in the same table one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I Suppose you are using a variable that you are changing somewhere in the Control flow and that is not reflecting properly to the expression.

I always use a Config table for such For each loops with file system

Table Defination

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_SSIS_InputMapping](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Conn_Mgr] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MD_File] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Input_Path] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Output_Path] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Archieve_Path] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [File_Format] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [File_Type] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Package_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Active] [char](1) NULL,
    [AttachOutput] [char](1) NULL)
```

My Folder Structure looks like this

```
MainFolder\MetaData
MainFolder\Input
MainFolder\Output
```

My Config Table look like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7taoo.png)

MetaDataFile is required for the validation of package. As you may move the input file after processing it. But the next time the package initiate , it will look for the file (which is moved/deleted) and it will fail.

This is a very generic approach which can be tailored as per your needs